# Use an operator between an array and an int

Tags: c#, arrays, int, operator-keyword

I'll need to create an loop to display all prime numbers till a certain number. The number will be inputted by the user him self. So I want to create a while loop to display the messages. Only I can't use an operator "<" between an array and an int.

```
int[] Prime = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11};

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int OutputPrime = 0;
        while (Prime < biggestPrime)
        {

        }
    }
```

This gives me the following error at the while line:
**Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int[]' and 'int'**

Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two words, _operator overloading_

Comment: @NullException You cannot overload an operator that would let you compare an `int` and an `int[]`, nor would you want to even if you could in order to accomplish this.

Comment: you should use your `int[]` with numerical index, something like `Prime[0] < BiggestPrime`

Comment: What does it mean for `biggestPrime` to be greater than the collection `{2, 3, 5, 7, 11}}`?  You compare two numbers, but you don't compare *sequences* of numbers.  You need to think through what you *actually* want to happen when performing this check (in plain English, not mathematically).

Comment: In simple terms, you can't do this because your loop doesn't know which item in the array you're accessing, nor in what order. You need to use a foreach or for loop probably, and access the items in order, comparing each one to the biggestPrime to check whether they are bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Prime` is an array type which holds some integer so you have to access its value using its index number, but you are trying to access `Prime` directly which is an array not an integer so compare with integer type `biggestPrime` throw exception You can achieve like this

```
int[] Prime = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11};

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int OutputPrime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Prime.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Prime[i] < biggestPrime)
            {
                // do your stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: should be `Prime[i]`

Comment: This is a *really* bad idea, as you're doing an enourmous amount of unnecessary work in each iteration of an already expensive operation.

Comment: Why would you initialize the array again in the event handler?

Answer (score 1):

Linq is your friend.

```
foreach (var prime in primes.TakeWhile(i => i <= biggestPrime))
{
}
```